# Motivation of the product of two binary quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Consider the binary quadratic form (over $\Bbb{Z}$) $Q(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+3y^3$ and $q(x,y)=x^2+5y^2$.

Lagrange
observed that
$$
Q(x_1,y_1)Q(x_2,y_2)
= q(2x_1x_2 + x_1 y_2 + y_1x_2 + 3y_1 y_2, x_1x_2 − y_1 y_2)
$$

> Could one come up with a possible motivation for such identity?

[**Edited**] one can *prove* the identity above by expansion. I'm wondering if one could come up with an idea of *deriving* the identity. The following is what I tried:

---

One can easily show that
$$
2Q(x,y)=q(2x+y,y).
$$
Also, $q(x,y)q(u,v)=q(xu-5yv,xv+yu)$. 
Hence we have
$$
q\circ q=q
$$
and thus $2Q\circ 2Q=q\circ q=q$.

But I don't see how this might help for showing the identity $Q\circ Q=q$.

Comment: some of this is just incorrect. Please get some of the references I mentioned, or others (older) by Dickson or by Mathews. I don't expect you will be able to reproduce Lagrange's line of thinking out of thin air. A different recent one is by Daniel Flath, Introduction to Number Theory.

Comment: At a minimum, do not leave out the $x,y$ variables. So, for example, $$ q(2x+y,y) q(2x+y) = q(?,??) $$

Comment: I added a general worked example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Will. I can now see your point in the previous comment. The factor 4 can eventually be cancelled out if one keeps the variables in the calculation of $2Q(x,y)2Q(u,v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the easiest examples of Gauss composition involving forms that are not equivalent to each other; the formula usually attributed to Brahmagupta on this site covers the case of repeating the "principal" form.. For positive binary forms, required primitive, the "reduced" forms make a group under the operation you are displaying. You have $q \circ q = q$ and $Q \circ Q = q.$ What you are missing is $Q \circ q = Q.$ The group operation is commutative, and the form that represents $1,$ which is your $q,$ is the identity element.

Many, many, many books deal with this. My favorite is Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms*. David A. Cox, *Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2,$* also gives a pretty complete discussion of this.

Probably the easiest way to deal with this is Dirichlet's approach, pages 55-57 in Buell, pages 47-49 in Cox.

One general thing, which caused some confusion in the beginnings of the subject, is the fact that $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and $\langle a,-b,c \rangle$ are inverses in the group, and should generally be regarded as distinct. I worked out the case of even middle coefficient from Arndt's algorithm. We get
$$ (a  u^2 + 2  b  u  v + c  v^2)  (a  x^2 - 2  b  x  y + c  y^2) = X^2 + (ac-b^2)Y^2, $$
where
$$ X = a  u  x - b  u  y + b  v  x - c  v  y, \; \; \; \; Y =  u  y + v  x.  $$

Now, this gives your identity back, for $\langle a,2b,c \rangle =\langle 2,2,3 \rangle$ by putting a minus sign on one of the variables, I 
guess $y.$ Your form is called "ambiguous," it is its own inverse in the class group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and references! I should have put my question correctly that I was originally interested in how to get the identity Lagrange observed.

Comment: I think what I got is $q\circ q=q$ and $2Q\circ 2Q=q$ and I don't see how to get $Q\circ Q=q$.

Comment: @Jack, no, there is no 2Q in this setup. It is not a ring or module. The discriminant of $ax^2 + bxy+cy^2$ is $\Delta = b^2 -4ac.$ Both your forms have discriminant $-20.$

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I think that's the part I don't understand. Lagrange's observation gives $Q\circ Q=q$. But I don't see how I can come up naturally with Lagrange's identity. (Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question accordingly.)